# Combine XML and Java file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, apk

I have the source code of an apk file and the individual XML files from Java files and I need to know how to put them together in order to import them into Android Studio to modify the project.

Comment: Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects. From the Android Studio menu select File > New > Import Project. Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, select Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.). Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.

Comment: yah that's right but you know when you try to get source code from apk you get XML files Separately from Java and i need to know how to put them togethor so i can import them into andriod studio

Comment: You can't combine XML and java files... They are separate things...

Comment: sure but what am i asking here is there any kind of things to do like  put that files in some folders before import them into andriod studio

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a directory structure externally on your own, It will be very difficult. Instead, try to create a new android project in android studio.

- Copy all the java files in src > main > java directory.
- Copy all the xml files in src > main > res directory. (follow
  android's format i.e. all layout files should go in layout directory,
  drawable should go in drawble directory and so on)
- Try to relate the xml files to java files, find out which activity or
  fragment has used which layout and make those changes.

Although, it is very difficult to figure out every thing this way in a huge project, it could be easy if project is very small.
If you are new to java and xml, my suggestion is to learn some basic concepts first. Just putting the files in those directories can't help you build the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to combine xmls like integrate title bar inside any activity you can use this.

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_titlebar"/>
```